# Do unrelated designations make any difference while looking for a new job?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, job-change, work-experience

I have been working on the development of a platform for the past 2 years. But my team (Tools/Development) is a small team within a large QC (Quality Control) team. Unfortunately my job title has to be kept like "Software Engineer - QC" only. The company policies don't allow it to be changed to "Software Developer" or anything else related to development.

Now I am looking for a new job. I am very confused whether my current designation is going to lessen my chances in getting opportunities in software development. How can I let potential hirers and headhunters know that I have been actually doing software development? How should I approach headhunters and interviewers about this?

Comment: This question [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume) seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Why would you choose "Software Developer" over "Software Engineer"? "Software Engineer" is several steps up, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your job title, you put some of your activities and achievements.  Those will show that you've done development, not just QC work.  Companies understand that titles don't always reflect the job done, nor are they consistant from company to company.  What you did at that job is always more important than your title, and your resume should be clear in showcasing what you did.

```
Acme, Inc (Software Engineer - QC) - June 2009 to present
On a team of 8, developed software in C# with a SQL Server backend, also using
Java, SSIS, and a bit of C++.  Worked with users developing new software.
Implemented a process that reduced bug reports by 10%, and led the process
changing from standard waterfall to agile.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write your CV to  use general titles that reflect your actual Job - at BT my grade was (MPG 2) but in my CV I used a industry relevant term.

As long as you job title reflects the role accurately there should not be a problem.

Comment: This is great until you put the wrong job title on your resume and then fail a background check... which I believe is the question Anand is asking, how to handle situations where the job title is not what you do. Are you suggesting to simply change your job title on your resume from what your company called it to what you define it as?

Comment: So most companys will only say Mr/MS X worked here for Y years. And background check who are you trying to work for some company where the HR director has Walter Mitty fantasys and needs to get over its self.