# Never had specific job titles so what should I do with my resume

Tags: resume, ethics, title, job-description, mental-health

I'm being treated for depression and I'm "cursed" with honesty. The titles I held with former employers and my specific job roles I held don't match what I want to change to.

In many of the roles I've had as senior developer & technical leader, I've written realistic project plans, lead scrums, written project documentation, done the actual project management work of resource allocation, timelines, meetings, negotiation, task allocation, epics, user stories, managed sprint planning, standups and retrospectives and designed effective sprints so that networking,infrastructure and operations are factored into the development plan and kept up to speed with where they  fit in and are required. Often I've either been asked to do that by the actual project manager or "helped" to write realistic plans to match the actual work to be done and manage the team doing it.

I know I have the skills to do project management, but I have a block when it comes to re-writing my CV to remove the development aspects and (in my mind) dramatically change what I have  done to focus on Agile Project Management.

I feel very dishonest about changing the official job titles on my employment contracts from my former employers as they mostly include the programming language (senior c# this, .net team lead that) and the descriptive text in my resume is written to back up that title.

I've been tasked by my psychologist to re-write my resume to better reflect the roles I would like to do and jobs I want to apply for. I feel very hampered by my employment history and that's also compounded by not having any agile or pm qualifications and my MSc is CS as well.

Frankly, I feel typecast and as recruiters with my existing resume keep on  phoning and emailing me for programming roles - I'm finding it hard to see how to get out of the trap. In my mind if I was to leave in the official job title and focus on the leadership, agile and PM duties then there is a screamingly obvious mismatch between title and duties.

Comment: For the job titles aspect of this question, don't be inaccurate about your job titles, but do take a look at similar questions about this topic. e.g. http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume

Comment: The core question has been asked before which makes this a duplicate. Specific to your question: you're interpreting your psychologist's advice incorrectly. Yes, he said to rewrite your resume so it's a better match for the roles you're looking for, but that does not mean lying about your job titles or work experience. Also, jobs normally aren't simply handed to you but if they are, as is the case with recruiters for in-demand profiles, then those will always work off your actual experience, not what you're looking for. Too much to say for a comment. Join chat if you need more input.

Comment: Having reread my question and reviewed the comments my core question is how to stop being typecast, by myself, my history and by recruiters who hold my resume. As such I've accepted that the core is a duplicate.

Comment: Can't answer due to duplication, but as Lilienthal says target the role to highlight relevant experience.  I had to do the same for many years due to generic job titles, countered it by having a work history section at the end with bullets (Jun 1999- Aug 2004 Dagoba Inc - Senior Nerfherder) which is what the background check people will concentrate on when doing a check, doesn't matter to them if you say your an Agile project manager as long as when they go to Dagoba Inc asking about the Senior Nerfherder role it checks out.