# How do I describe a role where I study different software solutions in my CV?

Tags: resume, software-industry, internship, job-description

As an intern, my current role is to study different stream processing frameworks, in order to integrate them later (by me) into a platform created by the company. By studying a framework, I mean reading its documentation, understanding its architecture & concepts, installing it to a cluster, and learning to use its API to develop and deploy an example application.

How do I describe such a task in my CV? 
Working on stream processing frameworks? 
Doing a state-of-the-art of stream processing frameworks and integrating them?

I feel like these descriptions are not specific enough and do not emphasis the fact that I took time to understand and become familiar with using each framework.

Comment: sounds like a research role

Comment: Sounds to me like some kind of software engineering.

Comment: evaluation and R&D

Comment: How involved are you in the final decision on which one to adopt?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is typically called developing a "**Proof of Concept**". While your CV should obviously keep the job title you currently have ([add something](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/13502/25739) like Software Developer in brackets if you don't have a title as an intern), you can describe it with one or all of the following:

- proof of concept implementations of [frameworks X, Y, Z  /  # stream processing frameworks]
- deployed and developed for cluster frameworks
- integrated [X, Y, Z / # frameworks] into [platform]
- analysed frameworks to determine best-in-class solution / fitness for purpose

Note that the latter probably doesn't apply to you if you're using them all but it's typically why a project like this is done.

Answer (score 1):

"Research and integration of stream processing frameworks".

On the assumption, of course, that this phrase would make sense to a prospective employer. If the CV is going to a recruiter, you may need to dumb it down a bit; perhaps add " such as xxx, yyy and zzzz." so that it has the buzzwords that an automatic CV system would search for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess state-of-the-art can be used if you are working in a structure/department oriented towards R&D, even more if the roles you are targeting with your CV involve research to some extent, as this term is commonly used and totally makes sense in that context.

If you are not actually producing something (that could be production code, or documentation on the frameworks), you will have a hard time emphasizing what you've done for your company, so maybe it's better to stress the "R&D experimenting" aspect in your description.