# Implying management experience on a resume

Tags: resume

I am trying to move up to supervisory roles.  At one job, I was the right-hand-man to the guy in charge.  I traveled with him, advised him, and helped him out with management tasks, and also mentored other employees who were my same pay grade.  I'd like to spin this on a resume to help me get into supervisory roles.  "Administrative assistant" doesn't sound right.  How can I phrase this?

Comment: Did you have a title?

Comment: @mcknz - Yes, and I use that title and work description on my current resume.  But I'd like to shift focus to the supervisory type stuff that I did, unofficially, as the lead's right hand man.

Comment: This question might be useful: [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume)

Comment: Your title wouldn't happen to be "Assistant to the Regional Manager," would it?

Comment: Bad idea to use a different title - because when the new employer calls your current/ex-employer for a reference their first question is "so, how long did horse hair work for you as a <made-up title>?" and the answer will be "oh, he wasn't a <made-up title>, he was an administrative assistant". Keep the title, and list what responsibilities/duties you had in that role

Comment: @mcknz - My title was Chief Engineer.  I was a technical worker entirely, the managerial stuff was unofficial and happened because the boss needed help, and him and I got along well.

Comment: I think Chief Engineer is a pretty good title and already implies some leadership or supervisory experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> At one job, I was the right-hand-man to the guy in charge. I'd like to
>   spin this on a resume to help me get into supervisory roles.

There are two ways for you to point out your abilities and lean them toward a supervisory role.

On your resume, you list these activities as details in the section that describes your role.

My Title - Big Corporation, Inc. (2001 - 2016)

- did the usual work for the title
- did more work for the title
- Performed assistant and advisory duties for the CEO
- Mentored junior employees

Basically, you just fold the activities you want to highlight into the normal activities you performed in your role.

The second way is to highlight these activities in your cover letter. There you just describe what you did within a paragraph or two, and indicate how this will be valuable in the supervisory role you are seeking.

Answer (score 4):

I would focus on your responsibilities and what you actually did -- your description of those will highlight your management experience. The title is actually less important.

If you had an actual title at that job, consider using the title. In addition to the title you could add an alternate or additional title that describes work not captured by your actual title, such as: "Actual Title \ Managerial Associate" or "Actual Title (Assistant Supervisor)," then explain your dual role.

I don't think there's anything wrong with omitting less supervisory descriptions in favor of supervisory-related tasks. No one lists everything on a resume, so it's a matter of deciding what you want to highlight for that job, to fit the position you seek.

A resume should be closer to sales brochure than historical document.

Comment: The last line succinctly describes precisely what a resume is for. I'm going to use that. :)

Comment: A resume should be accurate. Let's say your title was "Administrative Assistant" and you were applying for new jobs, yet you put "Assistant Supervisor" on your resume. When someone calls that company to confirm employment, it may not work out when they ask if mcknz was employed as an Assistant Supervisor in a certain time window when, according to their records, you weren't. It's even worse if the title you choose to use is a title in the organization.

Comment: @ThomasOwens agreed -- my first recommendation was to use the actual title. In some cases people have titles that make sense internally but do not translate well to an outside audience.