# What is a programming/marketing position called?

Tags: position

I have been programming for 15+ years - and at the same time I have also worked with SEO and online marketing for 10+ years + run a big website in my freetime for a few years.

Being able to do both SEO/online marketing, programming and website management seems to be rather rare combination, so I have had several offers that aren't just standard programming jobs.

Think head of big websites, technical advisor for other programmers, content marketing tool builder, etc.

Currently I work as a normal programmer, but I would love to somehow market my special skill combination to potential clients.

Only problem is this: What is a person that combines programming and SEO/online marketing called?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: See also [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume)

Comment: Job title questions like this are meaningless, much like the titles themselves, and don't make useful for useful contributions to this site. See the [help] for details.

Comment: pre-sales or a very boring job...

Answer (score 4):

**This isn't something that can be easily summed up in a job title.**  As you note, it's a rare combination.  Even if there were some title that could cover it, it wouldn't be commonly known.

**Important ways to highlight your unique skill set:**

- **Make sure this is front and center in your cover letter.**  Most jobs you apply for will focus on one of the two areas of expertise.  Your cover letter should then emphasize the other set of skills you also have, and how this adds value
- **Emphasize this in the specific duties and responsibilities you have in your job.**  Perhaps by having two subsections, one for programming and one for SEO.  Two subheadings will make the two areas stand out, and make it clear that you consider both to be a major part of your job (e.g. you're not just a programmer who dabbles in SEO, or vice versa).

As for the job title, it isn't so important.  [The question already mentioned in the comments](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume) gives you some good options.  Or you could work with your employer to try to agree a unique job title that covers your role, or even two simultaneous job titles if you have two distinct areas of responsibility.  Basically, do your best on this, but it's not crucial.  What is crucial is the overall way you present your skills.

Comment: Good points, but I would love to find a good title so I can promote my skills on LinkedIn etc.

Comment: I'm not applying for any jobs.

Comment: @Louisa In what context are you promoting your skills? If it is for a CV or something like that, use your actual title but market your responsibilities/skills underneath as bullet points.