# How much do job titles matter to potential employers?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, job-description, title

I'm deciding on whether to take a job I was recently offered. I'm going from an engineering title to a representative title.

I like the company, pay seems good and I liked the people there. In the event that I do leave the company, how much does my title matter to potential employers? Will they see my job title from "engineer" to "representative" as a negative?

Comment: Usually Job titles matter few, as they are mostly company specific. What company A calls junior dev may be senior on others, etc. They will mostly see your experience and what you've done rather than the name of your job position.

Comment: What is a "representative"?

Comment: Relevant: [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/13494)

Comment: Usually some see the "representative" title and assume it's a call-center type of job. That's my fear

Comment: I've worked for (and seen) employers hand out titles like halloween candy. I know of one company where 75% or more of its personnel are supposedly management with half of them being director or higher. On the other hand, for some reason employers give more credence (in my experience) to the lower (aka peon) titles. The same person who's skeptical of a "senior director" I've seen take "junior developer" as an iron-clad description of ones' ability.

Comment: I don't think I'll worry about the title as much than. The company is a fortune 500 company so I plan to stay with them for as long as possible. After being laid-off and being unemployed for couple of months, desperation sets in lol.Thank you all for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're not misrepresenting the job title or the skills/responsibilities that you're doing, you should be ok.

However, if you're implying that you're doing something completely different (or letting the reader make that implication), then it's a bad thing (obviously).