# How do I word my current internship position on my CV?

Tags: resume, internship, applications

I got a summer internship at a reputable company.

I was initially accepted as a software development intern but as of now (a month has passed) I have not worked with any actual code, I have simply been auditing data and creating mock up designs for improvements to the web application.

I would really appreciate some help in wording this correctly for my CV as I do not want it to seem like I am lying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just write your actual position name in your CV, in your case software development intern (or whatever it is in the contract). It doesn't really matter what you have actually done during the internship. If you will apply for a new job the hr team or a dev will most likely ask you during the interview what you have been doing and what have you learnt during the internship. Then you could explain what you actually did and what are some areas you haven't touched at all.

Answer (score 1):

List the position name at the company, the same as any other job.
When the position does not match the duties, it's a good idea to list the duties (emphasizing the duties related to the position you're looking to get).

See [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume) for more details on handling jobs on your resume that may or may not match your duties fully.