# Adjust title on resume based on actual job performed?

Tags: resume, title

With my most recent job, I been hired as Senior Electrical Engineer - either due to mistake of an employer or some contract related issues (as I been told). However, for last 2 years, I have been mainly performing a job of a software engineer/developer - very little if any electrical work.

This now becomes a confusion since several recruiters would send me purely electrical engineering positions (probably by not reading full description of my current position).

Would it be appropriate to use "Senior Software Engineer" in my resume to better reflect that I do at my job for future job hunting?

Comment: Anything preventing you from leaving the title as-is, and describe what it really involved in a few sentences instead?

Comment: Actually this might be a better duplicate: [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/13494)

Comment: @Dukeling That is actually might be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In the cover letter and opening resume headline/profile I see no problem with this.
When actually listing work experience, perhaps no title. Changing would make me as hiring manager uneasy.