# Dilemma about which position title to put in resume

Tags: resume, title, position

I applied for the position of Head Teacher in an ESL school (my current workplace). However, up to now I deal with admin work and creating learning materials. It's a long story.

Anyway, I’m about to update my resume and start looking for another job, but my dilemma about putting the proper job title keeps me from updating it. I was thinking:

1. If I put my current position (admin staff) but the prospective employer does a reference check and call my boss, there would be a conflict because my boss would tell that he hired me as head teacher.
2. If I put the position I actually applied for (head teacher), answering interview questions specific to it wouldn’t be to my advantage. It would be difficult to make up things I didn’t actually do.

As much as possible, I wanna maintain accuracy without compromising my relationship with my soon-to-be former employer and the prospective one. So, which is the better choice between the two?

Comment: This has already been asked here several times before and answered. E.g. [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume)

Comment: Tell the truth in your resume. In other words, **list your actual job title, and then give a brief description of the duties you performed.** Elaborate in the interview, as needed, if asked.

Answer (score 4):

> So, which is the better choice between the two?

Head Teacher. This is your official position and you wont be putting any incorrect information.

While, I do not know much about ESL schools and job duties but "creating learning material" sounds closer to teacher's job than admin's job!

However, you can always mention some key responsibilities as a "head teacher" in your resume itself which would also clarify that your day to day work is closer to "admin staff"

Whatever is the "long story", you can explain it in the interview.