# Will my job offer be withdrawn/rescinded after background check?

Tags: resume, job-offer, background-check

I am freaking out at the moment.
I jumped the gun and gave my current employer two weeks notice before the employer would tell me if my background check is satisfactory. I know, stupid of me. The third company used to perform the background check is  Sterling Talent Solutions.

The reason why I am freaking out is because of two things:

My job title are a little different than what I original wrote on the background application form. For example, on the of jobs is a Operations Support clerk, I wrote that my title is an Operations Coordinator. It is not that I wanted to embellish the title upwards, but more of a title that I think really described what I did there. On the duties of this job, one of the requirements if "helping to coordinate and supervise the activities with the processing team"...so in a sense I am coordinating or supervising other people. I did not place Operations Supervisor as a title, just something along the lines of what I actually did. 
I know, what I should have done is placed Operations Support Clerk (Coordinator)...on the background check, this is what I wrote.

For my second job, my title was a Inventory Correspondent but on resume, I wrote Accounts representative, Inventory management. Again, not I was not trying to embellish anything upwards....just trying to account for what I actually did there.

My job description for both jobs are, 100% written with honesty.

The second is job hopping. My work history is like this:

May 2018 - Present, COMPANY C

Feb 2018-May 2018, COMPANY B - I resigned from this job as the location changed and I was not informed that I would be working in a different location in the beginning.

2016-Feb 2018, COMPANY A

I did not include company B on resume but did in the background check history application.

Before my background check, I provided to two references to HR.

I have a clean driver record, good credit score of 730, and no criminal history.

Do you think that these would impact my job offer?

Comment: For future reference consult: [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume)

Comment: No, I don't think it will impact your process. Credit scores don't matter as they do not look at it. They're looking if you pulled out loans and never paid them back. Or if you're pulling out large loans for no reason.

Answer (score 6):

Background check done by a third party is not your fair trial. They want bad apples absolutely out, but they want to raise all the minor warnings too, to prove their service is worth what the employer is paying them.

Omitting a job from résumé is irrelevant. It's not a document that is supposed to contain your each and every contract. It's *your* choice what jobs to put there to show off your experience.

The discrepancies in literal job titles are easy to find and will likely be reported, but will not fail an entire check. (The same goes with employment dates.) These will be passed to the prospective employer. If they are looking for a reason to fail you, who knows... But why would they waste their own effort? Recruiting is not much fun for them. So you are very likely to pass.

In future don't mess with the lines on your résumé that say `Bulbulator at Acme    2010-2012`. Anything else is pure marketing, but these lines are sacrosanct. If you feel you did a lot more than an "Inventory Correspondent", say so in the first line below `- In an Account Representative role I won 194 new customers per week`. Almost everyone understands that the job title rarely describes your true role. But the true role is in fact hard to determine from the outside, whereas the job title is very easy to confirm.