# Omit to list a job demotion on resume. Is it going to impact background check for a new job offer?

Tags: resume, job-offer, background-check, demotion

I have been extended a job offer and the company is going to process the background check for me. In one of my previous jobs, I was demoted to a senior analyst position from a manager position. Although my duty and pay rate was still the same after the title change, I left the company not long after that happened. On my resume, I only listed the manager title as I didn't know how to explain that short period of time being an analyst. But after I ran work history report from the work number, I realized that only the final job titles are listed. Should I change my job title to senior analyst in background check authorization form? Or do I need to talk to HR about this? I am worried that it is going to impact my job offer. Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume)

Answer (score 3):

If you can enter both titles then do so, otherwise just enter the final job title.  The purpose of the background check is to verify that what you claimed is accurate.

Also, if your duties and pay remained the same, this was nothing more than a title change.  You can explain that to HR should they ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if they uncover that detail, it wouldn't be a show stopper.  If I were hiring, I might ask what happened, but more out of curiosity and to see if you were a personality problem, and only then if I already had some misgivings.

Then again, if a company is going to dig that deeply, you might wonder if signing with them is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever heard of listing a demotion on a resume. Don't list a demotion on a resume. That's not a lie, since you're not ever expected to provide that information.

That said, listing the latest position -- Senior Analyst -- is a more common practice than listing the "highest" position -- Manager -- or the position held for the longest time -- whatever that may be. But there are still no hard rules here, so I don't imagine anybody would accuse you of lying.

If the background check happens to find this, and they happen to really, really care about the demotion itself, it might make a difference, but I doubt most companies dig that deep, and they won't necessarily know why your title changed or anything, so I wouldn't worry.

Is the job you interviewed for a managerial position? (This doesn't really change any of the above, but if it's not, I'm sure nobody cares).

Comment: Yes, the job I interviewed is a manager position, but still an individual contributor position.

Answer (score 0):

> work experience:
>   [...]
>   Company X, start date - end date 
>    - senior analyst
>    - manager
>   [...]

Done.

You can also elaborate on projects and responsibilities for both positions to add more detailed info.

**Benefit**: it would show you were longer manager than sr.analyst and people would assume you were hired as analyst and got promoted soon thereafter.
Once questions pop up during the interview or while working there, you still can(should) answer truthfully and explain better than in a CV.

**As for your current situation**:

Let things run their course.
 If you add new info now, you might draw their attention where it probably never would go.

Should you fail the test because of thus, you can always explain that you had both positions (I assume your contract or a reference will be able to prove that).