# Is it okay to use a different job title on my resume?

Tags: resume, job-description, position

My job title is not representative of the work I have done during my most recent position.

This isn't a situation where my title is some quirky one that only people inside the company would understand, I would say it's very common. However, my understanding of the wider use of the job title is that it comes with some connotations, and perhaps expectations, of experience which I do not have.

I don't want to oversell myself, I just want to accurately reflect what I have done.

My instinctive answer to this question would be yes, it's fine, provided I disclosed my actual title at an appropriate time and the reasons why I altered it. This would be so no flags would be raised when contacting references.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before in [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume)

Answer (score 4):

You are fortunate that your "official" job title oversells what you actually are responsible for.

My suggestion is that you **do not alter your title on your resume.** There are a few reasons I say this...

1. You do not want a potential employer to be be confused if references refer to your official title. You say that you could *"disclose my actual title at an appropriate time"*, but you do not know when that will be, or whether the interviewer will remember what you said when they contact references.
2. Technically, altering your title would be **lying**, even if you are lying to for the sake of being honest.
3. If you want potential employers to know the "truth" about your most recent position, then simply explain what you did in the job description on your resume.
4. You are the one who will be selecting which jobs to apply for, based on your experience. If your official title was *Senior Widget Maker*, but you had the responsibilities and experience of a  *Junior Widget Maker*, all you need to do is apply for *Junior Widget Maker* jobs rather than *Senior Widget Maker* jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with the original title and your opening line in the description you can explain why you think an alternative title was more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You can add a more descriptive title in parentheses after your official title.

EX: Senior Vice President, Human Resources (CHRO).